# why is JVM not allowing this to compile ?

Tags: java

```
public class CollectionTestImpl {

    public static void main(String[] args){

        List<Animal> ld1 = new ArrayList<Animal>();

        ld1.add(new Dog());
        ld1.add(new Cat());
        impl.addAnimals(ld1 );
}

public void addAnimals(List<? super Dog> animals){
        for (Animal animal : animals){ // this is not allowed compile error  
            System.out.println(animal.checkUp());
        }
    }

}
```

Why does JVM not compile for (Animal animal : animals) ??? is'nt this logically correct ?

Comment: public class Dog implements Animal

Comment: public class Cat implements Animal

Comment: public class Elephant implements Animal

Comment: `List<? super Dog>` means that the method works on lists of `Dog` and *supertypes* of `Dog`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`List<? super Dog> animals` is a list which can be reference to `List<Dog>` `List<Animal>` but also `List<Object>` since all of `Dog` `Animal` and `Object` can be treated as supertype of `Dog`.

And because of possibility of `animals` being `List<Object>`

```
for (Animal animal : animals)
```

can't work because not all Objects have to be Animals.

Answer (score 3):

Think about what types of `List` your `addAnimals()` method could take. Your generics indicate that it's a `List` of some **supertype** of `Dog`. So it might be a `List` of `Object`s!

And obviously, since it might be a `List<Object>`, then the compiler can't guarantee that everything in the list will be an `Animal`.